# How use GROUP BY DAY at DataSetTableAdapter in Report of Visual 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Current I'm trying to write a query to **get all day** of birth in month. And **group by same day of birth**.

**Example**:

```
SELECT        DayBirth
FROM            BirthDay
WHERE        (DayBirth LIKE '%' + '5/1990')
GROUP BY     ????????
```

**Table BirthDay**

```
 Name  |  DayBirth
--------------------
  A    |  22/5/1990
  B    |  18/5/1990
  C    |  3/6/1990
  D    |  18/5/1990
```

**Out Put**

```
DayBirth
--------
22/5/1990
18/5/1990
```

**Note**: I'm trying to write a query at **DataSetTableAdapter** in Report of Visual 2010, and trying to write a query same **DAY**(DayBirth), **DATEPART**.., **DIFF**..., in **SQL**.

But **error**: **Undefined function [Day],[DATEPART},[DIFF],... in expression**

Thanks

Comment: In your query you are matching against a day/year combination.  Do you really care about the year?

Comment: Why is this question tagged 'crystal-reports'?  If you are using Crystal Reports, it is easy to create a day group.

Comment: **Answer for Mark**: I'm interested in both years and months, days. I just want to grab all the birthdays in that month, and of course if the same day the group by it.

Comment: **Answer for Craig:** Sorry if I do you are not satisfied because the wrong tag set, I just think the relevant tag and will get answers. I just using **Report View** of Visual.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve for output from the query.  Can you create a sample of what you want it to return?

Comment: **Answer for Mark**: Thanks Mark, you're very enthusiasm. Sorry I was answer late. I've created a sample same you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [article](http://cephas.net/blog/2005/12/06/sql-server-group-by-datetime/).  I believe you are convert your date to a varchar and then group by that.  Choose your date conversion type (which is 111 in the query) below in this [article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

```
SELECT distinct convert(varchar,mydate,111) as thedate, count(id) as perday
FROM orders
group by convert(varchar,mydate,111)
order by perday DESC
```

Comment: **Thanks Emmie Gabrielle Lewis**, but still error **Undefined function convert**

Comment: Can you show me your sql?  I can do this in the Northwinds database and it works fine.

SELECT distinct convert(varchar,ShippedDate,101) as thedate, count(orderid) as perday
FROM orders
group by convert(varchar,ShippedDate,101)
order by 1 DESC

Comment: Use a stored procedure for your SQL in Crystal Reports.

Comment: **Thanks Emmie Gabrielle Lewis**